# InfoPath list Forms wont display

Tags: infopath

Have a 2013 farm and we use InfoPath forms for lists, internally they show up without any issue. However when accessing the form externally they show up blank, no errors.

Our farm is setup so that you can access it from outside, we do not have any issues opening InfoPath Form Library forms, they generate with no issue.

Is there a configuration that is necessary to enable this capability when a user is coming in from outside our network?

Comment: Is anonymous access activated? Or how are you authenticating externally?

Comment: no anonymous access, the web apps use negotiate so externally they just login when prompted, no sso involved.